# How can I convert a certain rating score by using the following information? (picture included)

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, gaussian

I've found this statistic online:

[image]

Males rate females on okcupid in a way which shows us (an almost perfect) Gaussian distribution.
Females on the other hand, rate males way different. They seem to be way more picky.

Me as male, I now have an attractiveness score rating from quite a number of females.

My question is now the following:
Can I somehow "convert" my attractiveness rating (that I got from females) by making the hypothetical assumption that females rate males the same way as males rate females?

How do I go about this?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to find the percentile (percent below) of your score among males (maybe 80th, score 4 out 7, according the the bottom graph) and then find the rating among women with the same percentile (maybe score of 6 out of 7 according to the top graph). All hypothetically speaking, of course, as you say.